# how to move mouse slightly in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

how do you write a code in AS3 that moves my mouse slightly(very slightly that can not even notice it had moved) automatically in every 5 seconds?

Comment: You need some precision servos and a suitable interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that with the original OS mouse. What you can try is to hide the mouse and create your own pointer.

```
// import that library
import flash.ui.Mouse;

// then somewhere in your code
Mouse.hide();
```

Once the mouse is hidden you may add a MovieClip which contains a graphic similar to the original pointer. After that use the [Tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) class to move the graphic smoothly.

Comment: if it is impossible to move mouse in every 5 seconds, is it possible to click automatically in every 5 seconds?
the thing is that, i made an app by Adobe Air with AS3 and the app turns off automatically in 10 seconds when its not touched. The reason why it turns off is because of the mobile setting, so I want my app to be turned on all the times by moving or clicking automatically in every 5 seconds.

Comment: Hm ... I don't think that this is kind-a possible. You may simulate a click event or something like that, but I'm not sure that this will trick the mobile settings. And to be honest that's kinda wrong. If the user wants to use your app without to be turned of then he should change its mobile settings.